# How to extract substring in the double quotes by using awk or other methods?

Tags: linux, awk

I want to extract *you* in this sample string:

```
See [ "you" later
```

However, my attempt does not work as expected:

```
 awk '{ sub(/.*\"/, ""); sub(/\".*/, ""); print }' <<< "See [ \"you\" later"
```

result:

```
 later
```

Using awk or other methods, how can I extract the substring in the double quotes?

Comment: If you can have input that only has 1 quote (`foo"bar`) or no quotes (`foo bar`) or multiple pairs of quotes (`foo"bar" and "more" stuff`) then add that to your sample input and show the expected outptu so we can see how you want those handled - all the answers so far will produce the output you want from the current sample input you provided but they'll each behave differently for the inputs I just mentioned,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1st solution:*** You can make use of `gsub` function of `awk` here. Just simply do 2 substitutions with NULL. 1st till 1st occurrence of `"` and then substitute everything from next `"` occurrence to everything with NULL and print that line.

```
awk '{gsub(/^[^"]*"|".*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` solution. Using its `-oP` option to print matched part and enable PCRE regex option respectively. With regex from starting match till very first occurrence of `"` and using `\K` option to forget matched part and then again match everything just before next occurrence of `"` which will print text between 2 `"` as per requirement.

```
grep -oP '^.*?"\K[^"]*' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awk solution without any regex:

```bash
s='See [ "you" later'
awk -F '"' 'NF>2 {print $2}' <<< "$s"

you
```

Or a `sed` solution with regex:

```bash
sed -E 's/[^"]*"([^"]*)".*/\1/' <<< "$s"
you
```

Another `awk` with `match`:

```bash
awk 'match($0, /"[^"]*"/) {print substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)}' <<< "$s"

you
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `cut` here:

```bash
cut -d\" -f 2 <<< 'See [ "you" later '
```

It splits the string with a double quote and gets the second item.

Output:

```
you
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/RCIxV0).

Comment: idk if the OP can have this situation but that would output `bar` given input of `foo"bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash`

```
IFS='"'
read -ra arr <<< "See [ \"you\" later"
echo ${arr[1]}
```

gives output

```
you
```

Explanation: use `IFS` to inform `bash` to split at `"`, read splitted text into array `arr` print 2nd element (which is `[1]` as `[0]` denotes 1st element).

Answer (score 2):

Just a few ways using GNU awk for:

multi-char `RS` and `RT`:

```
$ echo 'See [ "you" later' |
    awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' 'RT{ print substr(RT,2,length(RT)-2) }'
you
```

the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ echo 'See [ "you" later' |
    awk 'match($0,/"([^"]*)"/,a){ print a[1] }'
you
```

`gensub()` (assuming the quoted string is always present):

```
$ echo 'See [ "you" later' |
    awk '{print gensub(/.*"([^"]*)".*/,"\\1",1)}'
you
```

`FPAT`:

```
$ echo 'See [ "you" later' |
    awk -v FPAT='[^"]*' 'NF>2{print $2}'
you

$ echo 'See [ "you" later' |
    awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"' 'NF{print substr($1,2,length($1)-2)}'
you
```

`patsplit():`

```
$ echo 'See [ "you" later' |
    awk 'patsplit($0,f,/"[^"]*"/,s){print substr(f[1],2,length(f[1])-2)}'
you
```

the 4th arg to `split()`:

```
$ echo 'See [ "you" later' |
    awk 'split($0,f,/"[^"]*"/,s)>1{print substr(s[1],2,length(s[1])-2)}'
you
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n 's/[^"]*"\([[:alpha:]]\+\)"[^"]*/\1 /gp' input_file
you
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=").*(?=")' <<< "See [ \"you\" later"
you
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract *all* quoted substrings, and remove the quotes:

```
echo 'See [ "you" later, "" "a" "b" "c' |
grep -o '"[^"]*"' | tr -d \"
```

Gives:

```
you

a
b
```

- `""` is matched as an empty string on the second line of output (use `grep -o '"[^"]\+"'` to skip empty strings)
- `"c` is not fully quoted, so it doesn't match

For a small string, you may want to use pure shell. This extracts the *first* quoted substring in `$str`:

```
str='Example "a" and "b".'
str=${str#*\"} # Cut up to first quote
case $str in
    *\"*) str=${str%%\"*};; # Cut from second quote onwards
    *) str= # $str contains less than two quotes
esac
echo "$str"
```

Gives

```
a
```

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` example that works in BSD and Linux:

```
% echo 'See [ "you" later ' | awk -F\" '{print $2}'
you
```

For `sed`, use for both BSD and Linux:

```
% echo 'See [ "you" later ' | sed -e 's/^[^"]*"//' -e 's/"[^["]*$//'
you
```

For `php`, make a file called you.php:

```
<?php
$you = explode('"', 'See [ "you" later ');
echo $you[1], PHP_EOL;
```

Then run it:

```
% php you.php
you
```

For perl, find the content inside quotes:

```
% echo 'See [ "you" later| perl -pe 's/^[^"]*"(.*)"[^"]*(.)$/$1$2/'
```

Remove the `(.)` and `$2` if you don't wish to capture the newline.

Answer (score 0):

hands-free driving with `awk` :

```
echo 'See [ "you" later' | 

gawk ++NF OFS= FS='^[^\"]*\"|\".*$'  # any one of these 3, 
                                     # specific for this case
gawk '$_ = $--NF' FS='\"' 
mawk '$!--NF=$NF' FS='\"'  


you
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nE  'say $& if /(?<=")\w+/' <<< "See [ \"you\" later"
```