# Text in double quote with awk, and colum not in this delimiter (")

Tags: awk, double-quotes

I've this log file :

```
11/01/2023 (17:01) [INFO]       => root : "get()" from wrapper.py (line:156) in get()
11/01/2023 (17:01) [INFO]       => root : "get() : 200 " from wrapper.py (line:166) in get()
11/01/2023 (17:01) [ERROR]      => root : "<!> initialisation error : Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" from main.py (line:453) in <module>()
```

and, with awk, I want to get, for example $1 and $3 column, AND the text in double quote, like this :

```
11/01/2023 [INFO] "get()" 
11/01/2023 [INFO] "get() : 200 "
11/01/2023 [ERROR] "<!> initialisation error : Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
```

For the columns, ok :

```
awk '{print $1, $3}' mylog.log
```

Like this, but with the other(s) colum(s), like $1 and $3 :

```
$ awk -F\" '{print $2}' mylog.log
get()
get() : 200
<!> initialisation error : Expecting value: line 1
```

Have an idea please ?
Thanks

F.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract substring in the double quotes by using awk or other methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72854794/how-to-extract-substring-in-the-double-quotes-by-using-awk-or-other-methods)

Comment: IMO that question isn't the right dupe as it asks to find quoted string only not the mix of both like this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk` you can set `FPAT` to a double quoted string or any other non-quoted, non-whitespace string:

```bash
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^"[:blank:]]+' '{print $1, $3, $7}' file

11/01/2023 [INFO] "get()"
11/01/2023 [INFO] "get() : 200 "
11/01/2023 [ERROR] "<!> initialisation error : Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
```

Or use this awk solution on any version:

```bash
awk 'match($0, /"[^"]*"/) {
   print $1, $3, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}' file
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Your expected output shows `"get() : 200 "` in question. If that's not what you expected then please edit your question. Similarly on 3rd line as well my output is same as what you expected.

Comment: Thanks, but it break after "<!>. Like this : 11/01/2023 [INFO] "get()"
11/01/2023 [INFO] "get()
11/01/2023 [ERROR] "<!>

Comment: That means you don't have gnu-awk on your system. To use `FPAT` you need `gnu-awk`. You can use second alternative solution.

Comment: Like this if gwak is installed : $ awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^"[:blank:]] +' '{print $1, $3, $7}' test
3  ]        "get()"
3  ]        "get() : 200 "
3  ]       >

Comment: Don't use `FPAT` since you don't have gnu-awk. Just use: `awk 'match($0, /"[^"]*"/) {print $1, $3, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' file`

Comment: idem second solution... (with or without gawk). First not working too, sorry. Seems '<!>' cause some issues.

Comment: Working demo of the first solution: https://ideone.com/qqWzMZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251076/discussion-between-fabrice-and-anubhava).

Comment: Sorry I was offline for sometime, do you have any further query?